# ¿Por qué aparece así el archivo que subí a GitHub desde Git?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Quería hacer una pregunta sobre Git y GitHub.
Estoy aprendiendo a usarlos y tengo una duda:
El archivo que estoy pretendiendo subir es una carpeta, que dentro tiene otros archivos, pero cuando veo lo que se subió en el GitHub, realmente no es esa carpeta y me muestra con ese ícono. ¿podrían ayudarme?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez copiaste un repositorio dentro del tuyo.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente significa que dentro de esa carpeta tienes una sub carpeta de tipo .git Eso significaría que la carpeta (localmente) es un repositorio git anidado, puedes comprobar esto si dentro de tu carpeta aparece la carpeta oculta .git

intenta usar el comando:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules
```

eso deberia extraer todos los documentos de las subcarpetas .git

[image: Example]